# Connect to SQL Server 2022 DB Engine

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have installed SQL Server 2022 developer edition and SQL Server 2022 management studio successfully on my new Windows 11 laptop.
When I open management studio and attempt to connect to SQL Server DB engine I get the below error message.

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
> error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider,
> error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is
> not trusted.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2146893019)

When I installed SQL Server 2022 I selected the option to create a new certificate on installation rather the use an existing certificate.

I also followed the error helpfile instruction to export the certificate to the trusted folder from the Personal using MMC. This did not resolve the problem.

Any suggestions much appreciated?

After the error helpfile instruction to export the certificate.. I expected to connect to the DB engine. I also reinstalled SQL Server & the Express edition. The same error appeared.

Comment: *"SQL Server 2022 management studio"* FYI this doesn't exist; SSMS stopped have year named releases from SSMS 16 (which was coincidentally released in 2016). The SSMS release in 2022 was called SSMS 19 (and, last I heard, there *should* be an SSMS 20 coming this year).